# Which vehicle has the lowest fuel consumption?

Tags: unturned

If I were to travel exactly one mile by vehicle, which vehicle would consume the least amount of fuel? I'm asking this as I really don't like walking, but I don't like using up to much fuel either.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikia](http://unturned.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Vehicle), I couldn't find an official wiki, all vehicles in Unturned have the *same* fuel consumption. But fuel level is represented by the percentage of fuel that you have left, so a vehicle with a higher fuel capacity will appear to go down by a lower amount, but will then take more fuel to refill.

So if you're looking for a high fuel capacity, the APC and the Ural have the highest at 250 units. However, the Ural has a faster top speed of 65 km/h compared to the APC's 43 km/h. Also, the Ural has 8 seats, 3 more than the APC. Both these vehicles can be found naturally at a military base.

Answer (score 1):

I think because the fuel efficiency per distance is based on speed, the Roadster is the most fuel efficient. As of when this comment was written however, the bike is the most efficient as it uses no fuel.